# Recursive drawing of triangles not showing up

Tags: java

The point of this lab is to draw triangles that look like this:

[image: desired effect]

This is my code right now
[image: My code]

```
private void drawTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int colorIndex)
    {
    while((x2-x1) > 1){
      int[] xPoints = {x1, x2, x3};
      int[] yPoints = {y1, y2, y3};
      Polygon tri = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints, NUMSIDES);
      gr.draw(tri);
      drawTriangle(x1, y1 , x2/2, y2/2, x3/2, y3/2, colorIndex);
    }
    
}
```

what exactly is wrong with it because no matter what I do, no traingles are being drawn

Comment: Triangles that look like what?

Comment: Looks like what?

Comment: Make sure your title reflects your problem, this is supposed to be a repository of searchable questions and answers. "I am a APCSA student" doesn't sound like a question to me (or is relevant).

Comment: *"no traingles are being drawn"* That is because: 1) You don't call `drawTriangle()`. --- 2) The coordinates passes to `drawTriangle()` is outside the canvas. --- 3) The coordinates passes to `drawTriangle()` has `x1 > x2`, so loop is skipped. --- 4) Drawing a white triangle on a white background cannot be seen. --- 5) The `while` loop never ends since `x1` and `x2` aren't modified inside the loop. --- 6) The canvas `gr` is drawing on is not visible. --- 7) Some other reason I cannot fathom right now.

Comment: What is the point of `colorIndex`? You're not using it for anything.

Comment: the color index with come in the next part which I know how to do. I just need to get the triangles to be drawn

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while` to an `if` and the code will work fine.

You said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153267/recursive-drawing-of-triangles-not-showing-up/67156705#comment118700037_67153342) that "canvas is 550x550". You need to increase that to 570x590, to have room for borders and title bar.

With that, you get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the while loop, when will the while condition ever be true? My hunch of some code that never comes back seems true. Add some print statements in the loop to confirm.

Comment: Why do you think that? OP says that "**no** traingles are being drawn", not even the one with the original coordinates, so why would fixing the reduced coordinates make a difference?

Comment: @Andreas Because he is in an infinite recursion that will stack overflow.

Comment: I dont get a stack overflow error though. Literally nothing comes up. Also the canvas is 550x550 and this is the call that I did drawTriangle(5, 545, 245, 5, 545, 545, 0);

Comment: @AwesomeCuber Nothing appears because the GUI thread keeps drawing and never stops doing so. Rendering never happens and your app becomes totally irresponsive.

Comment: so is my base case incorrect?@Tarik

Comment: currently the base case is x2-x1 has to be >1. Also as a side not the picture is on the wrong side. its suposed to be going to the left

Comment: I did call my drawing in the paint component event. for some reason stack overflow wont let me add pictures so ill edit a picture of my code into the original post so you can see

Comment: @AwesomeCuber My mistake. My answer was non sense. See updated answer.

Comment: @Tarik It was called in the Paint Component event already